# CloseableHttpClient returning 504 on OpenShift tomcat pod

Tags: java, tomcat, openshift

Here is the problem:

We have a forward-proxy struts web app. All requests are forward to another mvc app, and responses redirected to forward proxy/struts app. Nowadays, it is deployed on iPlanet and rhel server.

We're moving (or trying to) the struts app to OpenShift and Tomcat. The application works fine on production, dev and uat environments and dev machine. On tomcat and jboss.

My problem is the following: one of our struts actions does the forward-proxy heavy lifting.

```
                            <action name="prepare"

                                            class="com.authentication.action.ProxyAction">

                                            <result name="success" type="proxy">

                                                            <param name="location">${path}</param>

                                                            <param name="parse">true</param>

                                            <param name="encode">false</param>

                                            </result>

                                            <result name="error" type="tiles">login</result>

                            </action>
```

The code for CloseableHttpClient code is as below.

```
                            CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()

                                                            .setSSLContext(sslContext)

                                                            .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)

                                                            .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)

                                                            .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())

                                                            .setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy())

                                                            .setDefaultHeaders(headers)

                                                            .build();
```

What happens on OpenShift pod, and only on OpenShift, is the 504 error.

The mvc app is receiving all requests from struts and returning them back. Curl on pod console also returns value, so I have discarded network issues.

I don't know what should I do next, has anyone faced this kind of issue before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not on CloseableHttpClient at all.

To mount the current url, we used to use request.getServerName(), which is does not make any sense on PaaS solution, as you have OpenShift pods and a Route to your system. This URL was then used as parameter to CloseableHttpClient, that's why we got a 504, the URL didn't exist in first place.